# month to season error in R

Tags: r

When converting a monthly data column (1 = Jan, 2 = Feb) etc. I keep getting the error 'Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 23) : undefined columns selected' when I input this code:

```
data[,23][data[,2]=="12"|data[,2]=="1"|data[,2]=="2"] <- "W"
data[,23][data[,2]=="3"|data[,2]=="4"|data[,2]=="5"] <- "SP"
data[,23][data[,2]=="6"|data[,2]=="7"|data[,2]=="8"] <- "SU"
data[,23][data[,2]=="9"|data[,2]=="10"|data[,2]=="11"] <- "A"
```

This should put each season into the 23rd column (and works on other datasets) but doesn't seem to work here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note .. how about using `%in%` instead of three times `==`?

Comment: hadn't thought of this, will try it to hopefully make it neater. Thanks!

Comment: Before you post a question, please check the `str(data)`, `dim(data)`, which will give you the info that there is no 23rd column, also the Error give some indications.

Comment: I realise it was more obvious than it appeared now, couldn't figure it out! I'll know in future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is no 23rd column in "data." That is why you are getting the error. Assuming that data has 22 columns, try preceding your code with the following:

```
data$season <- NA
```